# Delete a hidden field by its value

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a page with some values that looks like this:

```
 <div id="productList" >
   <input type="hidden" name="product[0].id" value="21">
   <div id="21" >BeanCounter</div>
   <input type="hidden" name="product[1].id" value="22">
   <div id="22" >CallGate</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to delete the hidden field with `value=21` and the div with `id=21`.

I have this:

```
function remove(id){
    var remove = $(id);
    $('productList').removeChild(remove);
```

But how do I delete the hidden field? Can you get an object by its value?

edit missed the mootools tag, not sure where the jquery tag came from. I guess mootools isn't that common but hopefully this could be done with plain javascript.

Hmm tag got changed back to jquery again?

Comment: Please check the Jquery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: what is `productList` is it id or class name. if class name then use dot(.) else if it is id then use #

Comment: dont use just numbers for id http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: -1 for not including jquery tag.

Comment: @NabeelSheikh It's not the wrong tag, this is Javascript..

Comment: @NabeelSheikh it's the right tag, and if you think i's wrong please suggest an edit

Comment: @Rode - What is `$` in this context? Is that jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mootools solution:

```
function remove(id){
    $('productList').getElements('input[value="' + id + '"], div[id="' + id + '"]').destroy();
}
```

jQuery solution:

```
function remove(id){
    $('input[value="' + id + '"], div[id="' + id + '"]').remove();
}
```

Comment: Was this a jQuery question?

Comment: @ChrisKempen, User seems to be using jQuery even though question has not been tagged. So, 50/50 I think.

Comment: It could be either jQuery or Mootools. If it's Mootools then the attribute selector is exactly the same anyway.

Comment: @ChrisKempen: I have done plain javascript version after user specified in his edit post. But I love this jQuery version more than mine.

Comment: Updated answer with a Mootools solution (OP has changed the tag).

Comment: since ids are unique: `$$("#productList input[value=" + id + "],#"+id).destroy();` - also, don't use numeric ids. prefix with an alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Using `plain javascript` *as mentioned* in the edited post:

```
var checkVal = '21';

var parentDiv = document.getElementById('productList');
var inps = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');
var inpRemove = null;

//Get the div to be removed
var divRemove = document.getElementById(checkVal);

for(var i=0; i<inps.length; i++)
{
   if(inps[i].value == checkVal)
   {
      //Get the input to be removed (Assuming only input with same value)
      inpRemove = inps[i];
      break;
   }
}

//Remove both here
parentDiv.removeChild(inpRemove);
parentDiv.removeChild(divRemove);
```

Comment: Thanks, good solution. Would vote you up if I could but I went with MrCodes mootool solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("DIV#21, INPUT[value='21']").remove()
```

Comment: Was this a jQuery question?

Comment: I suspect so from using the $ function.

Comment: Yes indeed, apologies... ;)

Comment: @AdrianBer, Mootools has also `$`